# Count in sequential order

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have a data set that has a list of id's and with those id's are a list of categories (so each id may have many categories). I want to search a list of categories and see how many different id's are within that category (count) but once a id is counted in one category it will not be counted in another.

Example:

```
ID  Category
1    Gas Station
1    Convenience Store
1    Barber
2    Day Care
2    Gas station
3    Convenience Store
3    Golf Range
```

So if I am doing a search of counts on gas station and convenience store (in that order) Gas Station will get a count of 2 (For id 1&2) and then Convenience store will get a count of 1 (id 3).

Currently my query looks like:

```
select category,distinct(id) from TABLE
where id in ('Gas Station','Convenience Store')
group by category
```

and it will give me

```
Gas Station - 2
Convenience Store - 2
```

And it's not what I want. Desired output:

```
Gas Station - 2
Convenience Store - 1
```

Comment: First, I assume you have an SQL error and meant to say "where Category in ..." instead of "where id in ...". Your discinct is grouped by category, so you are getting distinct values WITHIN category, not across the entire results set.

Comment: *"once a id is counted in one category it will not be counted in another"* - what's the rule for determining which category comes first - reverse alphabetical order? In other words, why isn't convenience store counted as 2 (IDs 1 and 3) and gas station counted as 1 (ID 2; ID 1 not counted as it has already been included in convenience store) ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear why you want this output but technically you can produce it with a query

```sql
SELECT category, COUNT(DISTINCT id) count
  FROM table1
 WHERE category = 'Gas Station'
UNION ALL
SELECT category, COUNT(DISTINCT id) count
  FROM table1
 WHERE category = 'Convenience Store' 
   AND id NOT IN
       (
         SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table1
          WHERE category = 'Gas Station'
       );
```

Output:

```
|          CATEGORY | COUNT |
|-------------------|-------|
|       Gas Station |     2 |
| Convenience Store |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/553bc2/3)** demo

Comment: @user2755209 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Try this as a single SQL:

```
SELECT Category
 ,COUNT(*)
 ,@ids:=CONCAT( @ids, ID, ',' )
 FROM Table1, (SELECT @ids:=',') ids
 WHERE Category IN ('Gas Station','Convenience Store')
 AND POSITION( CONCAT( ',', ID, ',' ) IN @ids ) = 0
 GROUP BY Category
```

SQLfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f026/12

**Updated**

Ok. try this:

```
SET @ids:=',';
SELECT Category
      ,COUNT(*)
      ,@ids:=CONCAT( @ids, ID, ',' )
  FROM Table1
 WHERE Category IN ('Gas Station','Convenience Store')
   AND POSITION( CONCAT( ',', ID, ',' ) IN @ids ) = 0
 GROUP BY Category
```

Modifying @peterm's sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f026/1) the results are:

```
CATEGORY             COUNT(*)   @IDS:=CONCAT( @IDS, ID, ',' )
Convenience Store    1          ,1,3,
Gas Station          2          ,1,
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I've played around with it in fiddle and it works but when I switch it over to my mysql it doesnt work - any ideas why?