# Understanding a qry using Position function and '@"

Tags: mysql

I recently asked a question where I was trying to figure out how to get a count of records that had a certain heading but once the record was counted with one of the headings it would not be counted again with another heading.

I received this answer in sqlfiddle and it works perfectly but I don't understand it and I am also not able to get it to work in my mysql database so was looking for an explanation and any reasons as to why this may not be working when I run it.

```
SET @pids:=',';
SELECT Condensedid
      ,COUNT(*)
      ,@pids:=CONCAT( @pids, PID, ',' )
  FROM Table1
 WHERE Condensedid IN ('Gas Station','Convenience Store')
   AND POSITION( CONCAT( ',', PID, ',' ) IN @pids ) = 0
 GROUP BY Condensedid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7174e/1

Comment: do you get an error in your database?  Your question also has another answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18667722/426671) that gives the same result without using variables - did you try that one?

Comment: wouln't be failing when the pid being looked for is the last one in the list would it?

Comment: as in 1,2,3, 3 has no , after it and so position will return 0 even though its there

Comment: The other answer works but is hard to duplicate over and over when I get requests for counts and it has 100 headings. The error I am getting is: <eb1>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Condensedid
      ,COUNT(*)
      ,@pids:=CONCAT( @pids, PID, ',' )
  FRO' at line 2
State: 37000; Native: 1064; Origin: [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.15]</eb1>

Comment: Are you submitting the query from a programming language? Are you trying to put both the `SET` and `SELECT` queries in the same `mysql_query()` call? Most mysql APIs don't allow you to put multiple queries in the same call, you have to do them with separate calls.